# How to get rid of {{ }} from scalars?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

I am confronted with the situation where a scalar appear within curly brackets like `a = {{2}}` (as example) and the subsequent operation involves multiplying `a` with `PauliMatrix[3]`. The answer should obviously be  `{{2,0},{0,-2}}`. However, the curly brackets seem to create problem and *Mathematica* tells me `"Objects of unequal length in {{1}}\ {{1,0},{0,-1}} cannot be \ combined."`

How to get rid of those brackets in `a={{2}}`?

Comment: You are most likely using column and row matrices instead of vectors. That is, you are probably doing something like `{{1, 2}} . {{1,2},{3,4}} . {{3},{4}}` when you should be using `{1,2} . {{1,2},{3,4}} . {3,4}`

Comment: `a[[1, 1]]` extracts the number from `a`

Comment: `{2}` is a list containing one element. `{{2}}` is a list of lists. You can address elements of the lists by specifying their parts.

Answer (score 4):

```
a /. List -> Sequence // Simplify
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to post a comment, but didn't have enough points.

```
a = {{2}};

Dimensions[a]

{1, 1}
```

Obviously you cannot multiply this with a 2x2 matrix.

A hack could be using: `Det[a]`. The output is a scalar and its Head is Integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the product of two matrices as follows:

```
〈matrix1_, matrix2_〉 := If[Dimensions[matrix1] == {1, 2} && Dimensions[matrix2] == {2, 1}, 
Inner[Times, Flatten@matrix1, Flatten@matrix2, Plus], Inner[Times, matrix1, matrix2, Plus]]
```

A test:

```
〈{{1,1}},{{1},{1}}〉
(*2*)
〈{{1},{1}},{{1,1}}〉
(*{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{2}};
PauliMatrix[3] * Cases[{a}, _?NumberQ, -1][[1]]
```

{{2, 0}, {0, -2}}

Turning this into a small function:

```
strip[x_] := Cases[{x}, _?NumberQ, -1][[1]]

a = {{{{{a}}}}};
PauliMatrix[3] * strip[a]
```

{{2, 0}, {0, -2}}

```
a = 2;
PauliMatrix[3] * strip[a]
```

{{2, 0}, {0, -2}}